# For positive semidefinite matrix $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, trace, positive-semidefinite

For positive semidefinite matrix $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}:$

$
\frac{1}{n}\text{tr} A = (\text{det} A)^\frac{1}{n}
$

Is this true?

Comment: Have you tried a few random examples?

Comment: Even a $2\times2$ diagonal matrix that's not a multiple of the identity will furnish a counterexample.

Comment: This is not true. Take the diagonal matrix [2, 0;0 ,3] to convince yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}.$$ We have that

$$(x\:\: y)\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}=(x+y)^2\ge 0.$$ Thus it is positive semidefinite.

Now, $\det(A)=0$ and $\rm{tr}(A)=2.$ Thus the equality you claim is false in general.